# Apply HttpSecurity for GET request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have this rest endpoint:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/data")
public class DataPagesController {

    @GetMapping("/page")
    public ResponseEntity<?> page() {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add("test 1");
        list.add("test 2");
        list.add("test 3");
        list.add("test 4");

        return new ResponseEntity<>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I have configured context path prefix into the project using:

```
server:
    port: 8080
    servlet:
        context-path: /engine
```

I want to restrict the access using:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .httpBasic()
       
        // Allow GET for dashboard page
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/data/page").authenticated()

        // Allow all requests by logged in users
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

But I get error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/engine/data/page 401
```

Do you know what is the proper way to configure endpoint permissions for GET request?

One possible idea:

```
 Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
19:12:37.834 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG AffirmativeBased[decide:66] - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@659a59ae, returned: -1
19:12:37.834 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter[handleSpringSecurityException:180] - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
```

I need to remove maybe `.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);`

Comment: And the problem is? The 401 is what you get if you are unauthenticated and you did protect the endpoint. So it is actually doing what you told it to do.

Comment: A bearer token isn't the same as basic authentication.

Comment: I agree. In my case what I can do? Here is the current progress: https://github.com/rcbandit111/OAuth2/blob/master/src/main/java/org/engine/security/WebSecurityConfig.java#L46

Comment: Properly configure Spring Security to use the oauth tokens.

Comment: No, it isn't due to a role as that is no role-based security. The fact is you haven't configured OAuth so there is no authentication going on and as you need to be authenticated to access your application you simply will never be able to access it. As stated configure oauth as explained in the either spring boot guide or spring security guide.

Comment: You said that you want to use oauth tokens, so I'm assuming you have the issuing of the tokens handled. What you need now is verifying the tokens right? You need to add spring security oauth2 dependencies after which you will be able to add a token introspection URI (I'm assuming you are using an identity provider). Please mention your applications security flow.

Comment: Yes I use `spring-cloud-starter-oauth2`. Here is the complete project: https://github.com/rcbandit111/OAuth2  and FE Angular https://github.com/rcbandit111/wiki-ui  Can you guide what I'm missing?

Comment: As per you config in question, every url is authenticated. And your question title implies only GET is not working. So can you provide details about how you are getting the `POST` or `PUT` to work and what headers are you sending?

Comment: I use Angular client to send data: https://github.com/rcbandit111/wiki-ui I can show you request data but I don't know is it going to be helpful?

Comment: The amount of configuration u r missing can’t be shown:) read a guide on spring security, start by implementing just spring security add oath later. You can’t just jump into spring sec without knowing what to do and expect it to work.

Comment: Give me some hint what is missing.

Comment: I am not even sure what do you want, the code is doing exactly what you are telling it to, which is only allow `authenticated()` requests. Now you need to create a way for yourself to authenticate yourself via oath. For that you need to **read a guide** on it -  https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

Answer (score 0):

401 means that you are not authorized, so it means you are not passing the token you have configured, or your are not passing as spring it is expecting, or the token you are passing is wrong / expired

> Similar to 403 Forbidden, but specifically for use when authentication is required and has failed or has not yet been provided. The response must include a WWW-Authenticate header field containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource. See Basic access authentication and Digest access authentication.[32] 401 semantically means "unauthorised",[33] the user does not have valid authentication credentials for the target resource.
> [401 error code from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#:%7E:text=See%20Basic%20access%20authentication%20and,credentials%20for%20the%20target%20resource.)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Maybe I need to add filter to inspect requests for Bearer tokens?

Comment: try to use this full example https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2/blob/master/custom-error/src/main/java/com/example/SocialApplication.java

Comment: I updated the code this way: https://pastebin.com/Yb2gvBaP but I have to add `spring-security-oauth2-client` which is not part of `spring-cloud` and now I get  `Bean method 'clientRegistrationRepository' in 'OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration' not loaded because OAuth2 Clients Configured Condition registered clients is not available` Looks like we need to think for another way?